# How to reference one control from another during inflation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, attr

I am trying to reference a sibling control through XML.

**To declare an attribute to reference an id from MyTextView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
        <attr name="valueTextViewId" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**fragment_example.xml - How to use custom attribute:**

```
<!-- Declare a "Title" text view that references a "Value" -->
<com.example.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    example:valueTextViewId="@id/bar"
    ... />

<!-- Depending on the "text" attribute of this "Value" textview -->
<!-- Do something within "Title" textview -->
<com.example.MyTextView android:id="@+id/bar" />
```

**MyFragment.java - Inflating the controls**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // calls MyTextView Ctor
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
}
```

**MyTextView class constructor - During inflation do something with referenced textview:**

```
public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
    int refId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyTextView_valueTextViewId);

    // Updated to use context
    if (refId > -1 && context instanceof Activity) {
        Activity a = (Activity)context;
        View v = a.findViewById(refId);

        // THE PROBLEM: v is null
        if (v != null) {
            // In my case, I want to check if the "Value" textview
            // is empty. If so I will set "this" textColor to gray
        }
    }
}
```

in this example `v` is always `null`. I assume because during Layout Inflation, the controls are not added yet. Another thing to note is that this is in a `Fragment`, therefore that might be the reason I cant find the view in the parent activity.

Is it possible to reference a control from another like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to reference a control from another like this?

It is possible to reference another `View` from a `View`.

But to do property checking in the **constructor** of a `View` is not advised.
There is no guarantee that any particular `View` is instantiated before any other during [View inflation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Compare these two layouts:
`first_layout.xml`

```
<com.example.MyTextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    example:valueTextViewId="@+id/bar" />

<com.example.MyTextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/bar" />
```

`second_layout.xml`

```
<com.example.MyTextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/bar" />

<com.example.MyTextView
    ...
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    example:valueTextViewId="@+id/bar" />
```

In this example, it's clear that property checking from the constructor will not work in one of these layouts.

I agree that it is possible to store the reference to another `View` within a `View`:

```
public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
    mReferenceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyTextView_valueTextViewId);
    ...
}

private int mReferenceId;

public View getReferenceViewFromActivity() {
    if (getContext() instanceof Activity) {
        return ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(mReferenceId);
    return null;
}

public View getReferenceView(View view) {
    return view.findViewById(mReferenceId);
}
```

But you should definitely do any and all property checking within the `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    MyTextView myTextView = (MyTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.foo);
    MyReferenceView refView = (MyReferenceView)myTextView.getReferenceView(view);
    //
    // do property checking
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if a textview with the id of bar is available within the id of bar, you can do something like this.

```
<com.example.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    ...
    android:tag="bar" />

<com.example.MyTextView android:id="@+id/bar" />
```

and

```
public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

      int barId = getResources().getIdentifier(getTag(), "id", packageName);
      TextView bar = mActivity.findViewById(barId);

    if (bar.getText() == "") {
        // Gray out this "title" textview
        setColor(android.R.color.gray);
    }

    // maybe set a text change listener to bar to make it future-proof
}
```

i would just pass the id as a tag on your MyTextView so you dont need to create a new attribute.

Comment: This is interesting and a start. However I don't have the ability to pass `mActivity` when I'm using `LayoutInflator`. That gets me wondering if the context attribute in the Ctor is the activity itself...

Comment: It can be. check via `if(context instanceof Activity)` and then cast it `((Activity) context)`

Comment: Perhaps do not do that logic in the constructor. Add a method to MyTextView for `setActivityValue(mActivity)` and then after the activity has been explicitly set, then do your logic of hiding or manipulating the other textview however you can.

Comment: I have updated the question. Context IS the activity. However I am inflating a `fragment` in that activity.

Answer (score 1):

Save the references in your own private fields in the constructor. In your case, save the refId in a private field. Then use them in the `onMeasure` function.

---

I would advice you not to use your approach of getting the referenced view. If you look at the usual cases, such as the RelativeView's children's `layout_toLeftOf`, you will notice that the id is always one of the children of the RelativeView and, hence, a sibling of the current view. In that case, it is easy to get the view by getting the parent, using `getParent()`, casting it to ViewGroup (not necessarily), and finding the view with the reference, using `findViewById`. If you can do this sort of limitation (id should be a sibling), you can perhaps get rid of this dependency on the context, which will eventually make your view unusable. You are probably better off setting the view using setBla() instead of using your own attribute (Maybe throw a runtime error in your onMeasure if this setter was not called).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no guarantee the `Activity's` layout is finished being created in the `Fragment's` `onCreateView()` method.

You could try this approach instead:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    mView.customMethodToSetTextColor(...)
}
```

`onActivityCreated()` is called when the Activity creation is finished, and after `onCreateView()` in the `Fragment` [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).